# Change All Tab Colors Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to change all the tab colors in my google sheet with a script

I know how to do it by putting in the name of each individual sheet

```
var summary = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
summary.setTabColor("f4c7c3"); // Set the color to red.
```

I also know how to get the name of all sheets

```
function getAllSheetNames(){
  var tabs = new Array();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length;i++)tabs.push([sheets[i].getName()])
  
  console.log(tabs);
  return tabs
```

But I don't know how I can set the tab color for every element in the array

Comment: Do you want to set different colors depending on the sheet names? Or why are you getting an array with the different sheet names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "in every element in the array" you mean the tabs variable, it's an empty Array.

```
function setColorToAllSheets(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach( sheet => sheet.setTabColor("f4c7c3"));
}
```

The above function use *method chaining*, `Array.prototype.forEach` and *arrow function* to set the tab color to all sheets in the active spreadsheet.

Comment: That is so much better than the initial script I wrote out myself, thanks so much!

Comment: Just a side comment, `tabs` won't remain an empty array in this case, the OP is pushing the sheet names to that array. I'd consider editing that out of the answer.